# Changing the node version of existing project to newer version with nvm

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm on Windows 10;

I have a project which I developed with vue and node `14.16.1`.

I am following a vue course and as a last step I have to upload the built project ( `dist` folder) in a simple firebase server, using

`firebase login`

but this command only works with node >=18, so I used `nvm` and I did

`nvm install 20.10.0` (last LTS version)

`nvm use 20.10.0`

And nothing wrong until here.

Then I just ran `npm run serve` on my project, and here comes the issue (sorry for the wall of text):

```
npm run serve
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.10.0\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js:31
    throw err
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@npmcli/config'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.10.0\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js
- C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.10.0\node_modules\npm\lib\cli-entry.js
- C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.10.0\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.10.0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.10.0\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v20.10.0\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\npm.js',
    'C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v20.10.0\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli-entry.js',
    'C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v20.10.0\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v20.10.0\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v20.10.0
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.10.0\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js:31
    throw err
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@npmcli/config'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.10.0\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js
- C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.10.0\node_modules\npm\lib\cli-entry.js
- C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.10.0\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.10.0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.10.0\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v20.10.0\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\npm.js',
    'C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v20.10.0\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli-entry.js',
    'C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v20.10.0\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v20.10.0\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

(yes, it's printed twice).
From what I can understand, for some reasons it can't find the `@npmcli` module, but I was not using it (I think).

To be sure, here's my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "vue-first-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.3.10",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0"
  }
}
```

I tried to check my environment variables, and here are they:

[image]

Since it's not the first time I have issues when I update node in projects, what should I usually do to avoid those problems? What should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

The issue is in `1.1.7` - `1.1.8` - `1.1.9` nvm version, I used nvm `v1.1.7`.

I had to:

- *IMPORTANT:* uninstall `npm 20.10.0` through `nvm remove 20.10.0`.

  Remember to check command line, sometimes it says `Manually remove C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.10.0.`
- update to `nvm v1.1.12` or above, using `nvm-setup.exe` you can find on this [link in github](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases);
- reinstall `nvm v20.10.0`

Now it should work.